# How to generate JQuery calls inside JavaScript FOR loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I need to generate this 4 JQuery calls inside a Javascript Function:

```
$(".dropdown-menu .1_147").hover(
  function() { $("#1_147").show(); },
  function() { $("#1_147").hide(); }
);

$(".dropdown-menu .2_147").hover(
  function() { $("#2_147").show(); },
  function() { $("#2_147").hide(); }
);

$(".dropdown-menu .3_147").hover(
  function() { $("#3_147").show(); },
  function() { $("#3_147").hide(); }
);

$(".dropdown-menu .4_147").hover(
  function() { $("#4_147").show(); },
  function() { $("#4_147").hide(); }
);
```

I've write a Javascript function, the FOR loop only generates the last interaction "4_147". How can I tell the Javascript to generate the 4 JQuery calls?

My current JavaScript:

```
var submenu_navigation = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu");
var submenu_navigation_list = submenu_navigation[0].getElementsByTagName('li');

/*console.log(submenu_navigation_list);*/

function generateDropdownMenuMoldura(lis_array) {

    for (var item in lis_array) {

        var item_class_attr_name = lis_array[item].getAttribute('class');

        console.log(item_class_attr_name);

        $(".dropdown-menu ." + item_class_attr_name).hover(
          function() { $("#" + item_class_attr_name).show(); },
          function() { $("#" + item_class_attr_name).hide(); }
        );


    }   
}


generateDropdownMenuMoldura(submenu_navigation_list);
```

Any clues?

Best Regards,

---

Update:

I got the solution:

```
/* Define the Elements that I need to loop */
var submenu_navigation = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu");
var submenu_navigation_list = submenu_navigation[0].getElementsByTagName('li');


function generateDropdownMenuMoldura(lis_array) {

    for (var item in lis_array) {

        var item_class_attr_name = lis_array[item].getAttribute('class');

        console.log(item_class_attr_name);

        (function(item_class_attr_name) {
            $(".dropdown-menu ." + item_class_attr_name).hover(
              function() { $("#" + item_class_attr_name).show(); },
              function() { $("#" + item_class_attr_name).hide(); }
            );
        })(item_class_attr_name);


    }   
}


generateDropdownMenuMoldura(submenu_navigation_list);
```

My question is: How this anonymous function call works? This is a recursion technique?

Best Regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript assigning event handlers via for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247928/javascript-assigning-event-handlers-via-for-loop)

Comment: here `var item_class_attr_name = lis_array[item].getAttribute('class');` you are getting class but later you are using `id` selector.

Comment: Have you checked if the loop is really giving you the 4 classes?

Comment: This may not look like a duplicate of that other question, but it's the same basic issue, and it comes up all the time.  In addition to that, you should not use a `for ... in` loop for the iteration; instead use a numeric index variable: `for (var i = 0; i < lis_array.length; ++i) { ... }`

Comment: @Quentin, I got it working with your link. I've posted the UPDATE. This technique is called recursively call an anonymous function? Best Regards,

Comment: you should never use a `for...in` loop on an array. also, the ID attribute should not start with a number.

Comment: @André — There's nothing recursive about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to fix your specific solution was already answered [in an other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247928/javascript-assigning-event-handlers-via-for-loop).

But why so complicated? Judging from the JavaScript you currently have, and assuming everything apart from the scope works fine,  a simpler solution would be:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li").hover(function() { 
    $('#' + this.className).show(); 
}, function() { 
    $('#' + this.className).hide();
});
```

There is no need to bind a different handler to each of these elements, since they all do basically the same thing.

Comment: wouldn't this select on ids like `#dropdown-menu 1_147 someOtherClass`? you'd need a way to isolate the `1_147`.

Comment: If you have a look at the first two lines of the OP's solution, you see that he is calling `getElementsByTagName('li')`. I just converted this directly to jQuery. If that is selecting the right elements for him, then this will too. Of course it would be easier to suggest a solution if we'd know the markup.

Comment: right, im saying that the `li` elements may have other classes on them, you can't just take the entire className attribute as the ID.

Comment: Ah ok, understood. But that's what he is doing as well: `var item_class_attr_name = lis_array[item].getAttribute('class');`.

Comment: true, i didn't notice that. this issue exists in his solution as well then :P

Comment: Exactly, but that's why my assumption is that if his code works for him (selects the right elements) and the problem is only the scope, my solution will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`jQuery.each('dropdown-menu')`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method . It is for loops.

**HTML Sample**

```
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery Sample**

```
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```